# Can someone help me analyze this article?

Tags: evolution, homework

I need to read this article — [**"Beyond the rainbow"**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2d8gyme0jv584mj/color%20vision%20evolution.pdf) by
*Marie-Claire Koschowitz et al.*, for an exam.

Following are some questions for which I could not figure the answer out after reading.

1) Why does this miniaturization necessitates insulation ? Following is quote from article: "*For fast-growing, presumably warm- blooded animals , such miniaturization would only have been possible with sufficient body insulation.* "

2) Dinosaurs suppose to have tetrachromacy. The article mentions "*dinosaurs were endowed with the highly differentiated color vision of birds*". Does this mean Dinosaur's "inherited" their tetrachromacy from birds ? Why does the article mention reptiles before that ? Are birds reptiles ?

3) The article starts talking about h*ow mammals develop fur and lost their highly differentiated color vision because they gave up structural color signaling*. What is the direct connection between mammals and the dinosaurs ? I don't see the parallel here....why bring the mammals into the discussion ?

4) What is the connection between *pennaceous feather and planar feathers* ?

Any or all questions answered is welcome ! Thanks !

Comment: You cannot ask for an explanation of an article. A) It would be too broad B) Homework questions are considered off-topic unless you show an effort. It is fine to ask something that you do not understand from a paper but that has to be a precise point. And the article is in clear and understandable english.

Comment: could you provide an actual link?

Comment: @shigeta Link provided

Comment: I do not think it realistic to expect anyone can explain an entire paper here. If you have a particular question, that is, if you do not understand a particular sentence, or small paragraph (that is, something concise) you may try to ask that.

Comment: @WYSIWYG I have updated the question to reflect effort and understanding. Please unmark it from "hold" so that I may receive some answers.

Comment: I think the question, although still broad (i.e., multiple questions) is eligible for re-opening. I have adapted my answer.

Comment: you guys are too tough on newbies - asking for clearer question should be first resort. closing second.

Comment: @JennaMaiz If you can then please ask some points as a new question. For example the vision part can be separated from the feather/fur part. Miniaturization can also be another question and there are some posts here related to that topic already; you may also have a look at those. I am voting for reopen but it would be nice if you narrow the question down.

Comment: Agree with @WYSIWYG. Also voting to reopen but there are probably too many different questions.

Comment: @WYSIWYG  What are the guidelines for asking a question like this ?(Can I even ask something like this ?) Moderators on this site are way too strict closing the question immediately and asking to show effort, reword, edit the question. I understand they have a job to keep this site clean-but all the same, my impression was this kind of site is not a good place to get a rapid response(like before a final as was my case). Anyways, if necessary, you can delete the question if it doesn't fit this sites guidelines.

Comment: @JennaMaiz: did you get a useful answer in time for your test? I admit some questions are shot at too quickly at times. I tried to do my best answering it, and we have re-opened the question for you, despite the fact that the question was, admittedly, too broad. We all do our best :) Good luck in the future and please don't hold back asking more questions. This question was very interesting and the article you linked was of notable quality and I loved reading it.

Comment: @shigeta I do think we should be a bit more friendly towards newbies, but don't necessarity find it hostile to close a question if the reason is communicated clearly and in a nice manner. In this case, the question is really broad, and it is asking several separate questions that should be posted separately. There are cases where several subquestions for a single paper/issue are suitable (e.g. clarifying several methodological steps). However, in this case, the subquestions are unconnected and they sometimes seem to deal with tangential statements in the paper (so dependent on other papers).

Comment: @shigeta Oops, sorry for reviving a really old discussion - didn't notice the timestamp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will answer the questions one by one-

- **Why does this miniaturization necessitates insulation ?**
  An organism's volume determines the total amount of heat that can be stored. The loss (exchange) of heat between the body and external environment mainly occurs on the skin's surface. Hence, body volume determines *how much* heat is stored, while body surface determines *how fast* that heat is dissipated to the environment. Volume increases with a power of three with radius, while surface increases with a power of two. Hence, smaller animals have large surface-to-volume ratios, which decreases rapidly with body size. Hence, small animals will dissipate relatively more heat per unit of time.
- **Dinosaurs suppose to have tetrachromacy. The article mentions "dinosaurs were endowed with the highly differentiated color vision of birds". Does this mean Dinosaur's "inherited" their tetrachromacy from birds ?** 
  No, birds are the closest living relatives to dinosaurs, and birds can be said to have inherited tetrachromacy from dinosaurs - see the cladogram below.

[image: cladogram]

- **Why does the article mention reptiles before that ? Are birds reptiles ?**
  Birds are not reptiles, they are separate classes within the animal kingdom.
- **What is the direct connection between mammals and the dinosaurs ? ... why bring the mammals into the discussion ?**
  Here below is another cladogram; there is no obvious, direct (evolutionary) connection between dinosaurs and mammals. The thing is that dinosaurs ruled the world before the last mass extinction, thereafter it were the mammals. That's why the authors discuss them both, I guess. Especially since we are mammals it may make sense to draw parallels.

[image: mammals dinos]

- **What is the connection between pennaceous feather and planar feathers**
  As far as I could track the two down, they are the same ([Prum, 2006](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.actazool.org%2Fdownloadpdf.asp%3Ffiletype%3Dpdf%26id%3D5012&ei=GtqYVPHtMMX98QWm6YGAAQ&usg=AFQjCNF_k4RgBrxSReVmtRC9_lCrpznZag&sig2=OmT6ci-WSCCa1tj96Rc_4w&bvm=bv.82001339,d.dGc))

Lastly, in response to your original question, before edits: [Here is a link](http://www3.uni-bonn.de/Press-releases/seeing-dinosaur-feathers-in-a-new-light) with a plain-English popular-scientific web article published online by the first author.